# Why do I get an infinite loop when using implicit conversions?

Tags: scala, recursion, pattern-matching, implicit, implicit-conversion

**Context**

```
object Fibonacci {
  final val Threshold = 30

  def fibonacci(n: Int)(implicit implementation: Fibonacci): Int = implementation match {
    case f: functional.type if n > Threshold => fibonacci(n)(imperativeWithLoop) 
    case f: imperativeWithRecursion.type => f(n)
    case f: imperativeWithLoop.type => f(n)
    case f: functional.type => f(n)
  }

  sealed abstract class Fibonacci extends (Int => Int)

  object functional extends Fibonacci {
    def apply(n: Int): Int =
      if (n <= 1) n else apply(n - 1) + apply(n - 2)
  }

  object imperativeWithRecursion extends Fibonacci {
    def apply(n: Int) = {
      @scala.annotation.tailrec
      def recursion(i: Int, f1: Int, f2: Int): Int =
        if (i == n) f2 else recursion(i + 1, f2, f1 + f2)

      if (n <= 1) n else recursion(1, 0, 1)
    }
  }

  implicit object imperativeWithLoop extends Fibonacci {
    def apply(n: Int) = {
      def loop = {
        var res = 0
        var f1 = 0
        var f2 = 1
        for (i <- 2 to n) {
          res = f1 + f2
          f1 = f2
          f2 = res
        }
        res
      }

      if (n <= 1) n else loop
    }
  }
}
```

**Example**

```
object Main extends App { // or REPL
  import Fibonacci._
  println(fibonacci(6)(imperativeWithRecursion)) // 8
  println(fibonacci(6)(imperativeWithLoop)) // 8
  println(fibonacci(6)(functional)) // 8
  println(fibonacci(6)) // 8
  println(fibonacci(40)(functional)) // 102334155
}
```

**Explanation**
I was playing with Scala and ended up with this code. It compiles and runs, but...

**Questions:**

1) Is there any difference (readbility, performance, known bugs, anything) between

```
case f: functional.type => f(n)
```

and

```
case `functional` => functional(n)
```

This is supposed to be more of a discussion, so I'm not only interested in facts. Any opinion is welcomed.

2) Look at the first line of the `fibonacci` method. Here it is:

```
case f: functional.type if n > Threshold => fibonacci(n)(imperativeWithLoop)
```

If I leave the 2nd parameter list `(imperativeWithLoop)` out, the code compiles but enters an infinite loop when I run it. Does anyone know why? The default implementation `imperativeWithLoop` is known to the compiler (no errors are produced). So why doesn't it get implicitly invoked? (I assume it doesn't)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the first question, there are small differences, but none that matter here. But it would be better if you uppercased the objects, in which case you could write this:

```
case Functional => Functional(n)
```

Regarding the second question, if you leave out `imperativeWithLoop`, it will select the implicit `Fibonacci` closest in scope -- `implementation` (which has already be found to be equal to `funcional`). So it will call itself with the exact same parameters as it had called before, and, therefore, enter an infinite loop.

Comment: Thx, I think I get it now. A compiler warning or something would be nice in such a case.