# Generate a sequence of Fibonacci number in Scala

Tags: scala, sequence, list-comprehension, fibonacci

```
  def fibSeq(n: Int): List[Int] = {
    var ret = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int](1, 2)
    while (ret(ret.length - 1) < n) {
      val temp = ret(ret.length - 1) + ret(ret.length - 2)
      if (temp >= n) {
        return ret.toList
      }
      ret += temp
    }
    ret.toList
  }
```

So the above is my code to generate a Fibonacci sequence using Scala to a value `n`.  I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this in Scala?

Comment: You should probably ask this on programmers.se. as it is, this question is too broad to be answered reasonably. There are lots of ways to define fibonacci sequences, and each has their owns strenghts and weaknesses.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388416/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-write-fibonacci-function-in-scala

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are many ways to define the Fibonacci sequence, but my favorite is this one:

```
val fibs:Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: (fibs zip fibs.tail).map{ t => t._1 + t._2 }
```

This creates a stream that is evaluated lazily when you want a specific Fibonacci number.

EDIT:
First, as Luigi Plinge pointed out, the "lazy" at the beginning was unnecessary.
Second, go look at his answer, he pretty much did the same thing only more elegantly.

Comment: Is it possible with for-comprehension construct?

Comment: Doesn't need to be a lazy val; being lazy just means that's it doesn't eagerly evaluate the first term 0, which  you already given as a literal

Comment: It seems like there should be a better way to do `(foo zip bar).map{ t => f(t._1, t._2) }`. In Haskell it would be `zipWith f foo bar`, and in Racket, `(map f foo bar)`

Comment: @DanBurton: In Scala you can write `(foo zip bar) map f` if f expects a tuple and `(foo zip bar) map f.tupled` if f expects two parameters.

Comment: Contrary to my previous comment, this *does* need to be a `lazy val` if it's defined as a local variable rather than an an object/class field. Because when it's a field the compiler translates `fibs` to `this.fibs`, so you can get away without the `lazy`. Meh. Probably best to keep it in for consistency.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge I would think that if it isn't lazy it would evaluate fibs, but since it's a stream it would stop the evaluation at the 3rd element. Still, making it lazy won't hurt.

Comment: Using scanLeft is a better solution. This solution will Not work  for takeWhile (4000000).sum

Comment: Streams memoize their elements, so this solution will cause a lot of memory allocations and degrade performance. If we aren't going to reuse the stream, it's better to use an Iterator instead, like in this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39436970/336881

Answer (score 93):

This is a bit more elegant:

```
val fibs: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fibs.scanLeft(1)(_ + _)
```

With Streams you "take" a number of values, which you can then turn into a List:

```
scala> fibs take 10 toList
res42: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34)
```

Update: I've written a [blog post](http://luigip.atwebpages.com/?p=200) which goes more detail regarding how this solution works, and why you end up with a Fibonacci sequence!

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know about scanLeft, that's really cool.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Isn't this a forward reference? Only works if I apply the `lazy` keyword.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen actually it depends where you're defining it. If in the top level of an `object` or in the REPL, you don't. If it's within a method then you do need the `lazy`.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Could you explain why this matters?

Comment: @DCKing It's due to scope. A member of an class can refer to any other member, and it doesn't matter what order they're defined in. But in a method, you can only refer to things that have been defined above.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge How can we do it as a method without using the lazy keyword?

Comment: Why would you want to do it as a method? That would cause it to recalculate the sequence every time. Changing the "val" to "def" above will work, but you go from O(n) to O(n^2) because it needs to re-evaluate the whole sequence for each recursive call. Which is bad.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge I understand your point but I want to learn immutable style programming in scala using this fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Beautiful solution, but may I know how to implement the same with `Long` type? Running `fibs(200)` is giving a negative number. Replacing `Int` with `Long` throws a compilation error.

Answer (score 7):

Not as elegant as Streams, not lazy, but tailrecursive and handles BigInt (which is easy to do with Luigis scanLeft too, but not so with Tal's zip - maybe just for me).

```
@tailrec 
def fib (cnt: Int, low: BigInt=0, high: BigInt=1, sofar: List[BigInt]=Nil): List[BigInt] = {
  if (cnt == 0) (low :: sofar).reverse else fib (cnt - 1, high, low + high, low :: sofar) }
```

> scala> fib (75)
>   res135: List[BigInt] = List(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073, 4807526976, 7778742049, 12586269025, 20365011074, 32951280099, 53316291173, 86267571272, 139583862445, 225851433717, 365435296162, 591286729879, 956722026041, 1548008755920, 2504730781961, 4052739537881, 6557470319842, 10610209857723, 17167680177565, 27777890035288, 44945570212853, 72723460248141, 117669030460994, 190392490709135, 308061521170129, 498454011879264, 806515533049393, 1304969544928657, 2111485077978050)

Comment: Similar: `def fib(n: Int, s: List[BigInt] = List(1, 0)): List[BigInt] = if (n <= 2) s.reverse else fib(n - 1, s(0) + s(1) :: s)`

Comment: BTW to convert Tal's version to handle BigInt, *all* you have to do is change `[Int]` on the left hand side to `[BigInt]`! The Int literals on the right are implicitly converted.

Answer (score 7):

My favorite version is:

```
def fibs(a: Int = 0, b: Int = 1): Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(a, fibs(b, a+b))
```

With the default values you can just call `fibs()` and get the infinite `Stream`.

I also think it's highly readable despite being a one liner.

If you just want the first `n` then you can use `take` like `fibs() take n`, and if you need it as a list `fibs() take n toList`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another approach again using **Stream**s on an intermediary tuples:

```
scala> val fibs = Stream.iterate( (0,1) ) { case (a,b)=>(b,a+b)  }.map(_._1) 
fibs: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> fibs take 10 toList
res68: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this implementation to be more legible:

```
def fibonacci: Stream[Int] = {
    def loop(a: Int, b: Int): Stream[Int] = (a + b) #:: loop(b, b + a)
    loop(0, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fib:Stream[Int] ={
  def go(f0: Int, f1:Int): Stream[Int] = {
    Stream.cons(f0,go(f1,f0+f1))
  }
  go(0,1)
}
```