# Fixed point in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, fixed-point-iteration

Is there a shortcut for the following code snippet?

```
while (true) {
  val newClusters = this.iterate(instances, clusters)

  if (newClusters == clusters) {
    return clusters
  }

  clusters = newClusters
}
```

I would like to calculate the fixed point, i.e. execute a function such that its result is stable. Are you aware of any higher-order functions that would suit my purposes?

Answer (score 1):

An adaptation from a fixpoint calculation example from *Scala By Example* by Martin Odersky (Chapter 'First-Class functions', Section 5.3),

```
val instances = ...  // from question statement 

def isApproxFeasible(x: Clusters, y: Clusters) = some_distance_x_y < threshold

def fixedPoint(f: Clusters => Clusters)(initApprox: Clusters) = {
  def iterate(approx: Clusters): Clusters = {
    val newClusters = f(approx)
    if (isCloseEnough(approx, newClusters)) newClusters
    else iterate(newClusters)
  }
  iterate(initApprox)
}
```

where function `f: Clusters => Clusters` delivers new candidate clusters, and `initApprox` corresponds to the first, initial guess on a fixpoint. Function `isApproxFeasible` helps ensuring termination for *a priori* threshold.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see any difference to my approach apart from the fact that you're using recursion. Unfortunately, it does not make my code any shorter or more readable.

Comment: No worries, misinterpreted "higher-level functions" by "first-class functions" :) Perhaps library/package functions may be another naming that conveys the enquiry :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to combine the famous one-line Fibonacci numbers computation (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864521/788207) and `takeWhile`:

```
val reductions = Stream.iterate(clusters)(this.iterate(instances, _))
(reductions, reductions.tail).zipped.takeWhile { case (p, n) => p != n }.last._1
```

Another approach, which would not require constructing a stream object in memory, is to use iterators:

```
Iterator.iterate(clusters)(this.iterate(instances, _))
  .sliding(2)
  .dropWhile { case prev +: next +: _ => prev != next }
  .next()
  .head
```

Although the imperative solution will likely be more efficient because it is a simple loop without stream construction or closures invocation.