# How to implement a recursive Fibonacci sequence in Scala using FS2?

Tags: scala, stream, fs2

While trying to become familiar with FS2, I came across a [nifty recursive implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9867004/3096687) using the Scala collections' Stream, and thought I'd have a go at trying it in FS2:

```
  import fs2.{Pure, Stream}
  val fibs: Stream[Pure, Int] = Stream[Pure, Int](0) ++ fibs.fold[Int](1)(_ + _)
  println(fibs take 10 toList) // This will hang
```

What is the reason this hangs in FS2, and what is the best way to get a similar, working solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is that `Stream.fold` consumes all elements of the stream, producing a single final value from the fold. Note that it only emits *one* element.

The recursive stream only terminates when 10 elements have been emitted (this is specified by `take 10`). Since this stream is not productive enough, `fold` continues to add values without stopping.

The simplest way to fix this is to use a combinator that emits the partial results from the fold; this is `scan`.

Also, FS2 can infer most of the types in this code, so you don't necessarily need as many type annotations.

The following implementation should work fine:

```
import fs2.{Pure, Stream}
val fibs: Stream[Pure, Int] = Stream(0) ++ fibs.scan(1)(_ + _)
println(fibs take 10 toList)
```

Comment: Ugh, actually started with trying scan, but had some syntax issues and switched to fold. At least I learned the difference between fold and scan...

Comment: More info for the functionally unadept: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17408881/3096687