# confusion re: solution to fibonnaci numbers with Scala infinite streams that used a def'd method within a def

Tags: scala, fibonacci, overriding

I have been studying some posts on scala infinite streams to better wrap my 
head around this concept.  I liked the simple solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388416/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-write-fibonacci-function-in-scala/7392006#7392006), 
which I have reproduced below:

```
def fib: Stream[Long] = {
  def tail(h: Long, n: Long): Stream[Long] = h #:: tail(n, h + n)
  tail(0, 1)
}
```

My initial understanding of what was going on was that we were returning a Stream[Long] object
with the tail method overriden.  To test out that (seemingly incorrect) hypothesis, I did the 
following, which would not compile:

```
def fib: Stream[Long] = {

  override def tail(h: Long, n: Long): Stream[Long] = h #:: tail(n, h + n)
     ^
     |
   ~error~~~

  tail(0, 1)
}
```

So this solution does seem to be based on an override.   So, now I'm wondering.. what exactly
is going on with Scala constructs that have a def of some type 'T' where the value of that 
block contains another def that, on first glance seems to override a method of T ?

Thanks in advance for enlightening me !

EDIT - here is the result of trying out the solution in the excellent answer from 
Mateusz Dymczyk
:

```
object Foolaround  extends App {

  def fib: Stream[Long] = {
    def pail(h: Long, n: Long): Stream[Long] = h #:: pail(n, h + n)
    pail(0, 1)
  }

  var x = fib.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.head
  println (s"results: ${x}")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To override a method `X` you would have to first create a class that `extends` some other class that contains a method `X` already. In your example you are actually not creating a new class anywhere! Here you just created a nested function inside another function which, unfortunately, is called `tail` (so has the same name as one of the functions inside the `Stream`).

So basically the `fib` method is returning a `Stream` instance which is recursively created by your nested `tail` function. To create the actual instance of the `Stream` that method is using the `#::` operator.. You're not creating a new class, just a new instance.

The [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream@#::(hd:A):scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A]) explains well what `#::` is doing.

Try changing the name from `tail` to `myTail` (or any other name that's not part os the `Stream`) and you'll see it still works.

As for why would you use this construct: one common reason is to structure your code, you can notice that you cannot use that `tail` function outside it's outer method.

Comment: Ahh. got it. i tried renaming tail to pail.. but the trick is.. as you say.. the 'pail' function is not usable outside the definition of 'fib'.   I should have realized this is a method within a method. Thanks for pointing that out.